# $('#addFilter').click(); not working

Tags: jquery, click

I've looked around and I've tried the following suggestions and none of them have worked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addFilter')[0].click();
    $("#addFilter").trigger( "click" );
    $('#addFilter').click();
```

Code:

```
var liSavedFilters = strSavedFilters.split(',');
$(liSavedFilters).each(function (i, v) {
    debugger
    $('#fieldSelect').val(v);
    $('#addFilter').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#addFilter')[0].click();
});

$('#addFilter').on('click', function () {
    debugger
    var $this = $('#fieldSelect option:selected');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" value="Remove All" class="btn apl-button-small " id="clearButton" />
    <input type="button" id="addFilter" value="Add" class="btn apl-button-small pull-right" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

The second debugger isn't triggering, anyone know why?

The HTML is not created view jQuery, it's the only ID on the document and there are no console errors.

Comment: Is the `#addFilter` element appended to the DOM after the page loads? Are there multiple elements in your page with the same `id` of `#addFilter`? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Check update please

Comment: It looks like you're triggering the click before the handlers are bound.

Comment: try to console  console.log($('#addFilter') );

Comment: @JananiKumar It returns the element

Comment: Have you tried  $('#addFilter').click(function(){alert("clicked!");}); ?

Comment: try events like $(document).find("'#addF‌​ilter").click(function(){
  console.log('event hired');
});

Comment: There are too many closing brackets at the end of code.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn First you do `$(...).click()`, then you do `$(...).onClick(function() {...})`. You trigger the click even on the element before specifying what should happen when you click the element.

Comment: can you show us the html part and what you really wanted to do.

Comment: @JasonP Just swapped them around, no change

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you have missed to declare **strSavedFilters** value
Code link here

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/yuvakom/1z2xv80e/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addFilter')[0].click();
    $("#addFilter").trigger( "click" );
    $('#addFilter').click();

var strSavedFilters ="split1,split2"

     var liSavedFilters = strSavedFilters.split(',');
            $(liSavedFilters).each(function (i, v) {
                debugger
                $('#fieldSelect').val(v);
                $('#addFilter').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#addFilter')[0].click();
            });

    $('#addFilter').on('click', function () {
    alert('message')
            debugger
            var $this = $('#fieldSelect option:selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I havent though. Or I wouldnt be able to get into the first debugger. I just omitted it from the code